# How to add an element for upcoming days after clicking button?

Tags: php

Why doesn't the following read the `nextday` class after clicking `nextbutton`?

My `prev` and `next` button code:

```
/prevbutton
$prev = date('Y-m', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m', $timestamp)-1, 1, date('Y', $timestamp)));
//next button
$next = date('Y-m', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m', $timestamp)+1, 1, date('Y', $timestamp)));
```

Here is my calendar code:

```
$day_count = date('t', $timestamp);

// 0:Sun to 6:SAT
$str = date('w', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m', $timestamp), 1, date('Y', $timestamp)));

$weeks = array();
$week = '';
$prevdays = true;
//Add empty cell
$week .= str_repeat('<td></td>', $str);

for ( $day = 1; $day <= $day_count; $day++, $str++)
{
    $date = $ym . '-' . $day;

    if ($today == $date) 
    {
        $week .= '<td class="today">' . $day; //CSS color:green
        $prevdays = false;
    } 
    else if ($prevdays)
    {
        //prevdays
         $week .= '<td class="prevday">'.$day; //CSS color:gray
    }
    else
    {
        //generate nextday
        $week .= '<td class="nextday">'. $day; //CSS bordered green
    }
        //close table of weeks
        $week .= '</td>';


    // End of the week OR End of the month
    if ($str % 7 == 6 || $day == $day_count) {
        if ($day == $day_count)
        {
            // Add empty cell
            $week .= str_repeat('<td></td>', 6 - ($str % 7));
        }
        $weeks[] = '<tr>' . $week . '</tr>';

        // Prepare for new week
        $week = '';
    }
}
```

In the first picture, the September 2018 read code works well, but in October 2018, it show all previous days.

Here is my output:

[image]

Comment: You seem to be missing a / on the first line of your code. Also, I am probably being dim, but where is the actual button click code?

Comment: here is my button click code
`<th class="next" id="next" style="visibility: visible;"><a href="?ym=<?php echo $next; ?>">&#8702;</a></th>`

Comment: help me please?

Comment: Sorry, i can't see a submit or an onclick? What am I missing?

Comment: there is no onclick i just call the variable $next into html my code `?php echo $next;?>`

Comment: So what makes your code process anything after the initial population of the screen, if you have no click action handling?